# Is there a way to circumvent windows path length limits without disabling it?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, path

While disabling windows path length limits makes it possible for some applications to use longer paths others are still not capable of dealing with long paths, because they have some internal checks.

How do I get around that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One trick is creating a virtual drive using `subst` that points to some directory.

If you have a folder already far down the file tree and want to work in it but some files are even further down like this: `C:\Users\my_really_long_username\my_extremely_long_working_directory_name_that_has_a_long_name_and_contains_even_more_folders_that_result_in_a_path_that_is_over_256_characters_long`

You can create a virtual drive like this:

cmd.exe:

```
subst V: C:\Users\my_really_long_username\my_extremely_long_working_directory_name_that_has_a_long_name_and_contains_even_more_folders_that_result_in_a_path_that_is_over_256_characters_long
```

powershell.exe

```
cmd /c "subst V: C:\Users\my_really_long_username\my_extremely_long_working_directory_name_that_has_a_long_name_and_contains_even_more_folders_that_result_in_a_path_that_is_over_256_characters_long"
```

You can then switch to the root of the virtual drive with `V:` and your programs think you are at the root of the filesystem even though you are technically in a folder really far down.

This obviously only works, if you have some kind of working directory from which you want to work and you can still get into path length limits if paths from this virtual root are longer than 256 characters.